# How to add extra delimiters to the end of a CSV file is some are found to be missing?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV file formatted like this:

```
A @ B @ C @ D @ E
```

It should have five columns, unfortunately, some are missing the last column, e.g.:

```
A @ B @ C @ D
```

How can I add an extra `@` to the end of every line which is missing the last column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the spaces are part of the field contents and the delimiter is "@" alone (although other variations can easily be accommodated):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "@"} {$5 = $5; print}' inputfile
```

AWK creates missing intervening fields. Setting a field value to itself preserves existing contents if the field already exists or sets it and any intervening created fields to empty strings.

```
$ cat inputfile
A @ B @ C @ D @ E
A @ B @ C @ D
A @ B @ C
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "@"} {$5 = $5; print}' inputfile
A @ B @ C @ D @ E
A @ B @ C @ D @
A @ B @ C @@
```

Comment: Alternately, you can say `{NF = 5; print}` which achieves the same result.

Comment: @glennjackman: Except that mine preserves fields in records that have more than five and yours truncates those records to five fields. Which one is desirable depends on the particular requirements.

Comment: +1 This is very clever. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @JS웃`: If you mean the part about creating intervening fields and setting field values to themselves, then [this is one place](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html).

Comment: Thanks @DennisWilliamson, appreciate the link. I never knew rebuilding a non-existent field would create those fields for lines which do not have that many fields present. It's like `perl's autovivification`. The document does explain how we can create new fields but didn't quite explicitly stated this feature. True gem. It's a shame we don't see more of your answers these days. Have to dig up old posts to learn! `:)` Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/@/&/4;t;s/\s*$/ @/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

untested, but something like:

```
perl -lpe '$n = tr/@/@/; $_ .= "@" x (4-$n)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
cat foo.csv | sed -E "s/([^\@]+\@){3}([^\@]+)/&@/" | sed -E "s/\@\@/\@/"
```

This reads the foo.csv file, then adds a @ after the fourth column, then removes the duplicates on lines that already had one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Python, here's a slightly smarter solution that adds as many @'s as necessary:

```
from sys import *

for line in stdin.readlines():
    stdout.write(line.strip())
    if (line.count('@') < int(argv[1])):
        stdout.write(' @' * (int(argv[1]) - line.count('@')))
    stdout.write('\n')
```

Call it like this: `cat foo.csv | python fixcsv.py 4`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'@' '{printf $0; if (NF == 4) {print "@"}}'
```

Note: Input `A @ B @ C @ D` will result in output `A @ B @ C @ D@`. I left the 4th value unchanged on purpose, but you can of course choose to add an additional space

Comment: since you drop the newline, you need to add `else print ""`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your fields cannot contain @, and you only want the replacement to occur when there are exactly 4 fields, this should be a working sed solution:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^@]*[[:space:]]@){3}[^@]+$/& @/' <<EOF
> A @ B @ C @ D @ E
> A @ B @ C @ D
> EOF
A @ B @ C @ D @ E
A @ B @ C @ D @
```

Note that `sed -r` assumes GNU sed.

Replace with a different redirect for use with a file.